# Getting undefined when I drill into my redux store

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using useSelector to retrieve my store. However when I `console.log(items)` there is data but when I do this `console.log(items.totalAmount)` I get undefined.

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const items = useSelector(state => state.items);

//I'm able to see the data
console.log(items)
```

The data when its logged

```
[{"code": "SR71", "description": "Keyboard", "quantity": 1, "selling_price": 166.99, "totalAmount": 166.99}, {"code": "10", "description": "Cement", "quantity": 7, "selling_price": 20, "totalAmount": 140}]
```

```
//I get undefined
console.log(items.totalAmount);
```

Could any please explain what am I doing wrong.

Comment: can you add what `console.log(items)` prints ?

Comment: Sure, I will re-edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` looks like this when you do `console.log`:

```
[
  {..., "totalAmount": 166.99},
  {..., "totalAmount": 140},
  ...
]
```

So you can access `totalAmount` of each items like: `items[0].totalAmount`

And for getting the `totalAmount` of all items, you can use:

```
let sum = Array.from(items).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.totalAmount, 0)
```

Also i used `Array.from` since there is no guaranty for items to be a serializable (normal) array. (as you confirmed that it was non-serializable .)

Comment: still getting undefined

Comment: @TonyNgomana updated the answer. it now contains the full code. are exactly using this code?

Comment: @TonyNgomana try `console.log(items[0].totalAmount)` and `console.log(items[0].totalAmount + items[1].totalAmount)` also.

Comment: @TonyNgomana also try `console.log(Array.from(items).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.totalAmount, 0))`

Comment: @TonyNgomana No problem. was the problem `Array.from` ? should i add it to answer?

Comment: It was Array.from, please add it to the answer

Comment: @TonyNgomana also try fixing the issue more clean, if not you may face future unwanted bugs. since normally a state variable should contains a regular array. so maybe you should use `Array.from(items)` when you set your state (not when getting the state), or maybe there is a problem with your redux configuration (like not setting up `thunk` middleware in redux), or ...

Comment: @TonyNgomana if you want to know more about is it okay no put non-serialized data (non-normal array) to store: https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state